# How to find out when svn:external was created

Tags: svn, external

Let's say, that I have directory in svn with svn:external set up:

```
$ svn propget svn:externals <url>/project_a/trunk/A
<url>/project_b/B B

$ svn info ^/trunk/A
(...)
Revision: 133416
(...)

$ svn info ^/trunk/A/B
svn: warning: W170000: URL '...' non-existent in revision 133416

svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist

$ svn log --verbose <url>/project_a/trunk/A
(no mention of directory B at all)
```

How can I find out who and when created this external?

Comment: Info you provided is not clear to me, but I just wanna ask, you say `(no mention of directory B at all)` does `B` actually exist under `<url>/project_a/trunk/A` ?

Comment: @JaiminAjmeri Yes. Directory `A/B` is created during checkout. I simply can't find a way to determine who nor when someone created this svn external.

Answer (score 1):

Run `svn log --verbose --diff --depth=empty <url>/project_a/trunk/A`. The command will display only the property changes made to `<url>/project_a/trunk/A`.

Comment: I am still waiting for this command to end, but I can assure you - it lists a lot more than only svn propedits :( (edit) --depth is also unavailable on svn 1.6, but it exists in svn 1.8 fortunately.

Comment: OK, it finally ended. Log lists all changes to directory passed as url, but `--depth=empty` makes `--diff` parameter work only for propedits. I still need to sift through history with grep or other tool to find who introduces property change. (in my case, developer added no commit message). Would you care to edit your answer for better explanation what `--depth=empty --diff` do? And what user should look for in output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you're looking for the first revision of the directory.

```
svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 ^/trunk/A/B
```